# Regex using js to strip js from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using jQuery to sort a column of emails, though they are base64 encoded in js... so I need a regex command to ignore the `<script>.*?<script>` tags and only sort what is after them (within the `<noscript>` tags).

**Column HTML**

```
<td>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write(Base64.decode('PG5vYnI+PGEgaHJlZj0ibWFpbHRvOmJpY2VAdWNzYy5lZHUiIHRpdGxlPSJiaWNlQHVjc2MuZWR1Ij5iaWNlPC9hPjwvbm9icj48YnIgLz4K'));
  </script>
  <noscript>username</noscript>
</td>
```

**Regex that needs some love**

```
a.replace(/<script.*?<\/script>(.*?)/i,"$1");
```

Comment: Are all of the emails located in `<noscript></noscript>` or the `<td></td>` is repeated for every email entry?

Comment: If every email is in a noscript block, why not just sort on jQuery("noscript").text()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the structure of the html doesn't change, you can use this:

```
$(a)​.contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3
}).eq(1).text();
```

It gets all text nodes and then filters to the one at index 1 and get's it's text value.

And if you want to stick with regexp, here's one:

```
a.replace(/(<script type="text\/javascript">[^>]+>|<noscript>.*<\/noscript>)/ig,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you're asking for (though I'm a little confused what you're asking for, to be honest...), but have you looked at using `document.getElementsByTagName('noscript')`? This function should return an array, the first element of which will be your `noscript` element.

Also, I'm not really clear on your overall approach to this problem, but it seems like you're misunderstanding the purpose of a `noscript` element. `noscript` elements only execute when the browser does not support Javascript, which means the only time `noscript` content would be displayed to the user is when the Javascript that you're using to modify the `noscript` content wouldn't run.

Perhaps you could clarify what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: When `noscript` exists in an element, it will still be a child of that element and still be selectable regardless of JavaScript being there. The only difference is that if JavaScript is enabled, it will be hidden. Getting the `textContent` of the `td` still returns the `script` tags and `noscript` tags.

Comment: Right. I guess I was interpreting his question to mean he wanted to use JavaScript to modify the content within the `noscript` tags to then display to the user, but that was probably a misunderstanding on my part.